# php export to excel not showing gridlines

Tags: php, excel

I have this code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");

header("Content-Disposition: filename=export.xls");
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```

It puts the data from a html table into excel, but the only problem is that i don`t see the gridline in the sheet. Am i missing something? Thanks

Comment: where does `$_REQUEST['datatodisplay']` come from ?

Comment: from a html page with a table. And all the data from the table (rows, columns) are exported to excel

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're getting in excel? Gridlines should always be visible on the screen, unless they've been set to white, or the background color of the cells has been changed.

Comment: i am also facing same problem . i am using office2007 to open the exported sheet. it gives message "the file you are trying to open has different format than specified by the extension"

Answer (score 4):

Today i run into same issue as OP did.

I found @Jayant Pandey answer to be really close to my needs! But issue was that grid border was bigger that header border so instead of `1px` i used `0.1pt`

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="border: 0.1pt solid #ccc"> 
   <--! SOME EXCEL CONTENT HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

I do know this is an old question but maybe someone is looking for this!

Answer (score 2):

Just set

```
 <body style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
```

in your HTML page that will render in excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you DO NOT have a "`background-color`" attribute defined for your HTML `<BODY>` tag.  That was my problem.  Remove it and all the gridlines will magically re-appear in Excel.

Comment: there is no such attribute. simple table without any attribute. still problem persist